# #react-native - Onesignal implementation

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm getting **this.handleNotification() / this.setState() is not a function** error when using inside onReceived(notification) {}, onOpened(openResult) {} Onesignal events  i have created. below is my code. 
Any solution for this. I'm implementing correctly or not ?

```
componentWillMount() {    
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);   
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.removeEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
}  

onOpened(openResult) {
    try {      
      this.setState({ msgBody: openResult.notification.payload.body });   
    } catch (error) { }
  }
  onReceived(notification) {
     OBJ.homeData.setNewMsgCount();     
     this.handleNotification('', '', '');     
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the context as code below:

```
OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived.bind(this));
```

Comment: Careful with this - `bind` creates and returns new function. You need to preserve the function references you pass to `addEventListener` so that you can pass the same references to `removeEventListener`.


`this.onReceived = this.onReceived.bind(this)`
Then:
`OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);`